# gamma or log gamma function in C or C

Tags: c++, c, numerical, gamma

I am seeking a C or C++ version of gamma and log gamma functions.

Are there any code pieces or libraries recommended?

If possible, I want to know the principle of the implementations.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Right the first google hits are http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_gamma.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use C++11: The GNU GSL has all Gamma function you would ever need: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Gamma-Functions.html#index-gsl_005fsf_005flngamma-583

Or you can have a look at boost's math special functions:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/lgamma.html

Comment: thank you, these code seem professional enough to use in industry.

Comment: @user I'd say they are, but make sure you comply with the license terms when you use them in your software.

Comment: yeap, boost is OK. We have to ignore GNU stuffs.

Answer (score 11):

In c++11, you can use [std::lgamma](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/lgamma) for log gamma, and [tgamma](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tgamma) for gamma.

Comment: I am not able to use c++0x now, but thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to have a look at [Numerical Recipes In C](http://www.nr.com/), it should contain the functions you need.