# What to do if tgamma() function is not defined?

Tags: c++11, c++builder, math.h, cmath, gamma

I am trying to use `tgamma()` from the standard library. When I try to compile, I get the error message:

> Call to undefined function tgamma

I have the directive `#include <cmath>`. I use Embarcadero C++ Builder XE3, which claims to support C++11 standards. What could be my problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit?  Only the 64-bit compiler supports C++11, the 32-bit compiler does not yet.  If you are compiling for 64-bit, then are you calling tgamma using the `std` namespace? `... = std::tgamma(...);`

Comment: How do I find out if I am compiling for 64-bit or not? I am on a 64-bit machine, but the IDE is installed in Program Files(x86). The compiler is supposed to support both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: In the Project Manager, the **Target Platforms** node allows you to add individual platform(s) that your project supports, and to set which platform is active at any given time. There are separate compilers for 32-bit and 64-bit, Windows and Mac, so you have to tell the IDE which platform to compile for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gamma or log gamma function in C or C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472803/gamma-or-log-gamma-function-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) contains a [`tgamma` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/tgamma.html).

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>
...
double rootPi = boost::math::tgamma<double>(0.5);
```

Of course, you can always switch to a different compiler, like *gcc*.