# Error:identifier tgamma is undefined in c++ although <math.h> is included

Tags: c++, identifier, math.h, gamma-function

Im trying to use tgamma function in c++ 10.It's running on a 32-bit machine. I've included , but still getting the error "identifier tgamma is undefined ". what could be the reason?

Comment: tgamma or tagmma ? In the later case, that's a typo.

Comment: sorry, you're right. tgamma.

Comment: Did you enable the c++11 standard?

Comment: i guess not.how should I do this?

Comment: @NavidAmin you should consult your compilers documentation (and you'll need a compiler that does support c++11). Here's a related question for one compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g

Comment: What do you mean by *it*? C++11 is a standard which specifies the c++ language and the standard library.

Comment: sorry but I dont understand why wouldn't it just run on c++10?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010 as the compiler

Comment: There is no such thing as c++10. The standard before c++11 was c++03. It doesn't compile on an earlier standard because `tgamma` wasn't a part of the standard library before that. Evidently, your compiler does not support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot use `tgamma` is because your compiler doesn't support the standard in which it was introduced. You'll need to use a compiler / standard library that does support c++11 or use another implementation of `tgamma` as advised in an answer to in a similar question [What to do if tgamma() function is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114928/what-to-do-if-tgamma-function-is-not-defined) which Resource kindly linked for you.

Answer (score -2):

math.h is C. Try this instead:

```
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: Have you checked for typo as in comment above - I know you're using tgamma, but have you actually typed tagmma?

Comment: no mate! no typo in the code. I've totally checked it.

Comment: Check out this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114928/what-to-do-if-tgamma-function-is-not-defined

Comment: Info for downvoters - the original question specifically included math.h.